# Is Day light time ending in USA

Tags: united-states, congress, legislation

There was couple of [news](https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/15/politics/senate-daylight-saving-time-permanent/index.html) regarding US Senate agreeing on Day light Savings time ending. But I do see it is getting continued. Will it end in 2022or 2023 ?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no indication that will happen as the bill is having issues in the house which is the next step in the process.

[Permanent daylight saving time hits brick wall in House](https://thehill.com/homenews/house/3571007-permanent-daylight-saving-time-hits-brick-wall-in-house/)

> More than four months after the Senate unanimously passed a bill to
> make daylight saving time permanent in the U.S., the measure has hit a
> brick wall in the House.
>
> The main impediments dimming the legislation’s chances of passing
> appear to be fundamental disagreements over its language and a general
> consensus that other matter take precedence as the House grapples with
> high inflation, gun massacres and fending off judicial threats on
> issues such as abortion and marriage equality.
>
> “I can’t say it’s a priority,” Rep. Frank Pallone Jr. (D-N.J.), the
> chairman of the House Energy and Commerce Committee, told The Hill
> recently.
>
> “We have so many other priorities, but it doesn’t mean because it’s
> not a priority that we’re not trying to work on it. We are,” he said,
> adding later, “If we can accomplish anything, it wouldn’t be until the
> fall.”

Another article from September 8th shows that no progress has been made on it as of yet.

[Permanent Daylight Saving Time Up in the Air as Bill Not Yet Scheduled for House Debate](https://www.nbcchicago.com/news/local/permanent-daylight-saving-time-up-in-the-air-as-house-mulls-when-to-consider-bill-2/2934856/)

> Earlier this year, the Senate unanimously passed legislation that
> would make daylight saving time permanent in the United States by the
> spring of 2023, but five months later it remains unclear whether the
> House of Representatives will take up the bill.
>
> The measure, sponsored by Florida Sen. Marco Rubio, would take effect
> in Nov. 2023, meaning that Americans would spring their clocks forward
> in March of next year, and then wouldn’t have to adjust the time after
> that.
>
> While the measure passed by voice vote in the Senate, it is not known
> at this time what the legislation’s fate in the House will be.
>
> House Speaker Nancy Pelosi, who has signaled that she supports the
> measure, has not yet scheduled it for debate in the chamber.
>
> It’s also unclear what the Biden administration’s stance on the issue
> is. After the bill passed the Senate earlier this year, then-White
> House Press Secretary Jen Psaki said the administration hasn’t
> formulated its position.
>
> “I have seen those reports,” she said. “I don’t have a specific
> position from the administration at this point in time.”

Comment: I thought all bills must go to lower house( House of Representatives)

Comment: @puzzled Most bills can start in either chamber of congress though there are some special ones that start in the house and a few things that only the senate handles. If a bill starts in the senate it will head to the house and they will vote on it. If there are differences they will work together to hammer them out.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now (September 2022), the [Sunshine Protection Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshine_Protection_Act) hasn't passed the House yet, and so isn't law.
There may be a renewed push to get it passed as we get closer to the "fall back" date of November 6th, but otherwise it'll die at the end of the 117th Congress just as it has before.

Comment: ok, https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75746/in-usa-which-house-a-bill-is-introduced-first

Comment: The "fall back" date isn't nearly as problematic as is the "spring forward" date. The transition to standard time means an extra hour in the bar for late night bar crawlers, or an extra hour of sleep for people who go to bed earlier than 2:00 AM. The springtime transition to daylight savings time is equivalent to jet lag, and that is bothersome to some people.

Comment: @DavidHammen It is also considered a health hazard and could cause serious medical issues by some in the medical field